# why is my /var/snap filling up so fast?

Tags: partitioning

```
nyck33@nyck33-ubuntu2304:/media/nyck33/2DA0F2CE46B4B745/fastapi/modern-apis-with-fastapi/ch05-a-realistic-api$ sudo du -sh /var/snap/* | sort -h
[sudo] password for nyck33: 
12K /var/snap/bare
12K /var/snap/core18
12K /var/snap/core20
12K /var/snap/flutter
12K /var/snap/gnome-3-28-1804
12K /var/snap/gnome-3-38-2004
12K /var/snap/gtk-common-themes
12K /var/snap/kf5-5-108-qt-5-15-10-core22
12K /var/snap/kf5-5-110-qt-5-15-11-core22
16K /var/snap/code
16K /var/snap/core22
16K /var/snap/gnome-42-2204
16K /var/snap/snapd
16K /var/snap/vlc
488K    /var/snap/cups
1.2M    /var/snap/snapd-desktop-integration
1.2M    /var/snap/snap-store
1.3M    /var/snap/skype
1.4M    /var/snap/discord
1.4M    /var/snap/okular
1.4M    /var/snap/spotify
22M /var/snap/firefox
nyck33@nyck33-ubuntu2304:/media/nyck33/2DA0F2CE46B4B745/fastapi/modern-apis-with-fastapi/ch05-a-realistic-api$ snap saved
No snapshots found.
nyck33@nyck33-ubuntu2304:/media/nyck33/2DA0F2CE46B4B745/fastapi/modern-apis-with-fastapi/ch05-a-realistic-api$
```

[image: gparted]

*delete ChatGPT answers*

I let Ubuntu decide how to install 23.04 and that is what it gave me.

Comment: please remove anything from chatgpt. it is untrusthworthy and unreliable as a source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `/dev/nvme1n1p4` is mounted at both `/` and `/var/snap`. Mounting at `/` means it's your root drive and will contain the majority of your files, it's not just Snap storing files on this partition.

Since you're using a gui I would suggest running `baobab` to see what's using all your space:
`sudo baobab /`

Comment: It is my cybersecurity folder with many VM's and Docker Images I found out with that command (about 132 GB).  I'll delete what I don't need, though I was doing that and then probably move everything else to an external SSD.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)